# store different lines of csv file separately

Tags: python

Is there a solution to treat different lines of csv file separatly?
what I want is to get a string containing the first line, a string s2 containing the 2nd line and the last string s3, containing data from the 3rd line to the `len(file)-1`th line

**My code is below**

```
with open("f1.csv") as f: 
    for line in f:  
    #s1 = 1st line
    #s2 = 2nd line
    #s3= from 3rd line no the len(file-1)
    print(line)
```

Comment: `f.readlines()` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Use `s1 = next(f); s2 = next(f); s3 = next(f)`

Comment: Sounds like you could just use a `list`, and indexing, if your variable names are `s1`, `s2` and `s3` anyway.

Comment: @Jab thank you i will try your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `f.readlines()`:

```
with open("f1.csv") as f: 
   lines=f.readlines()
s1=lines[0]
s2=lines[1]
s3=lines[2:-1]  #get 3rd to last line
```

Comment: thank you for your response . Thats what im using but the difficulties is to treat the lines #s1 = 1st line
    #s2 = 2nd line
    #s3= from 3rd line no the len(file-1)

Comment: Updated answer.